# Unresolved external symbol(LNK2019) and unresolved externals(LNK 1120)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, lnk2019

i am trying to import functions from a self built dll
the function in dll is:

```
std::string stringFunc(std::string str) {
         return str;
  }
```

in another project I try to call this function, Visual Studio shows error:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl stringFunc(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?stringFunc@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z) referenced in function main    YouCanDoAnythingHere    C:\Users\langj\source\repos\YouCanDoAnythingHere\YouCanDoAnythingHere\Source.obj    1
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Many things could be wrong. Perhaps you didn't export the function from the DLL. Perhaps you didn't link with the import LIB.

Comment: You should export that function. Use ``__declspec(dllexport)`` to export that function and then use ``__declspec(dllimport)`` to import that function from another project

Comment: @Asesh your suggestion works! thanks